# V3 QBO Custom Tax

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Is there any possible way of sending a QBO invoice up with a custom tax amount? I am taking invoices from my Shopify and Etsy stores and trying to send them up to QBO. In these cases I know the total tax amount already as Shopify and Etsy already calculated it and I just want to apply it to the QBO invoice.

If not I'm going to have to add tax as a line item :(

Comment: You can either enter the total amt(item price+tax) which you directly got form other systems or as you have mentioned, you can enter item price as Line and tax part as txnLineDetails in QBO.

Comment: If I use TxnTaxDetail i'd need to pick a valid tax code and tax rate and all that, which will be pretty difficult to do, matching up with my Shopify and Etsy stores. 

If I enter total amount with tax, and then line items without tax on the invoice, it's not going to calculate the difference as tax and display it or anything, I'd need line items with their prices and then a separate line item called tax, which is pretty uncool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this thread- [Quickbooks IPP v3 sales tax issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300885/quickbooks-ipp-v3-sales-tax-issue)

NOte that you will still have to assign an existing taxCoderef and the pass the oevrride flat amount.